# Using /ApplicationPublicName does not change AppName() output

Tags: broker

I know it's a long shot that there might be any uniPaaS developers on here, but here goes:

Today for the first time I've gone to duplicate a system we have in uniPaaS 1.5.

In the uniPaaS broker, I added the flag `/ApplicationPublicName` to change the
`APPNAME` that the application responds on.

However, the `AppName()` output that the application generates is still the
original name of the application, not what I specifying as the
`ApplicationPublicName`.

Our system relies heavily on `AppName()`. Is there any way to get `AppName()` to
return the same value as `/ApplicationPublicName`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better late than never to answer your own question I guess.

To work around this, we internally depreciated the use of the `AppName()` function, and instead replaced it with our own `IntAppName()`. Our new function does an `INIGet('ApplicationPublicName')` and returns that, as `AppName()` seems to always be fixed to the name of the application when it was compiled.

This was 4 years ago on 1.5 - perhaps v2.0 is different now, but we have continued to use our internal function without issue.

Answer (score 0):

the AppName() function returns that application name as it was defined in settings, application.

If you want the appname to return something else, simply iniput that value to the Magic_Systems section of the ini file.

Comment: Hi Noam, magic_systems was depreciated in eDeveloper v10. We have a whole bunch of Magic 9.4 applications where we overwrite the name in magic_systems, but uniPaaS doesn't have that setting

Comment: I Understand.

I don't know if it'll help, but we developed a technology that migrates magic based application to .net and have successfully completed projects based on  both client server, and merge. 

After the migration, you will not have the appname problem :)